# Redirect user after login

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm making a react application that integrates with an aspnet api, and I want to make the user unable to access other pages, except the Login page, without being logged in, I tried to do the following coding

This is the code I made, (it doesn't work as it should):

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignIn from '../pages/SignIn';
import Home from '../pages/Home'
import CadastroEmpresa from '../pages/CadastroEmpresa';
import CadastroIntegrante from '../pages/CadastroIntegrante';
import Empresas from '../pages/Empresas';
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';
import { LoginContext } from '../context/auth';


const Private = ({ Item }) => {
  const signed = useAuth();

  return signed > 0 ? <Item /> : <SignIn />;
}

export { Private }

const RoutesApp = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Fragment>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<SignIn />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<SignIn />} />
          <Route exact path='/home' element={<Private Item={Home} />} />
          <Route exact path='/empresas' element={<Private Item={Empresas} />} />
          <Route exact path='/cadastro-empresa' element={<Private Item={CadastroEmpresa} />} />
          <Route exact path='/cadastro-funcionario' element={<Private Item={CadastroIntegrante} />} />
        </Routes>
      </Fragment>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default RoutesApp;
```

useAuth() is my hook that uses the context below

This is my context:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const LoginContext = createContext();

const LoginProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [loginData, setLoginData] = useState({ status: '', token: '' });

  const validateLogin = (loginUser) => {
    if (!loginUser.email || !loginUser.senha) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };

  const passwordSignIn = async (email, senha) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('https://localhost:7223/v1/entrar', {
        email,
        senha
      });
      console.log(response.data)
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return {};
    }
  };

  const generateToken = async (email, senha) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('https://localhost:7223/v1/entrar', {
        email,
        senha
      });
      return response.data.token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return '';
    }
  };

  const handleLogin = async (loginUser) => {
    if (!validateLogin(loginUser)) {
      return setLoginData({ status: 'error', token: '' });
    }

    const result = await passwordSignIn(loginUser.email, loginUser.senha);
    if (result.succeeded) {
      const token = await generateToken(loginUser.email);
      return setLoginData({ status: 'success', token: '' });
    }

    if (result.isLockedOut) {
      return setLoginData({ status: 'locked', token: '' });
    }

    console.log(loginUser.email)
    console.log(loginUser.senha)

    return setLoginData({ status: 'error', token: '' });
  };

  return (
    <LoginContext.Provider value={{ loginData, handleLogin }}>
      {children}
    </LoginContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { LoginContext, LoginProvider };
```

Comment: provide the code for useAuth hook ?